# Install Perl module DBD::SQLcipher on Windows

Tags: sqlite, perl, sqlcipher

I need to install Perl module DBD::SQLcipher on windows 10 Perl version 5.16.
the ppm package says

```
c:\>ppm install DBD::SQLcipher
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides DBD::SQLcipher
```

and the cpan module gives error:

```
c:\>cpan install DBD::SQLcipher
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher/VirtualTable.pm blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher\VirtualTable.pm
cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher.pm blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher.pm
cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher/Fulltext_search.pod blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher\Fulltext_search.pod
cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher/VirtualTable/FileContent.pm blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher\VirtualTable\FileContent.pm
cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher/Cookbook.pod blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher\Cookbook.pod
cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher/VirtualTable/PerlData.pm blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher\VirtualTable\PerlData.pm
cp lib/DBD/SQLcipher/Constants.pm blib\lib\DBD\SQLcipher\Constants.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::SQLcipher ()
        C:\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 SQLcipher.bs
        C:\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\perl\site\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap C:\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap -typemap typemap  SQLcipher.xs > SQLcipher.xsc && C:\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- SQLcipher.xsc SQLcipher.c
Cannot open 'SQLcipher.xsi': No such file or directory in constants.inc, line 367
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\perl\bin\perl.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
  TGASIBA/DBD-SQLcipher-0.02.tgz
  nmake.exe -- NOT OK
```

Comment: On a linux machine, I have an extra step between the `chmod` and the `xsubpp` commands to generate `SQLcipher.xsi`. (By the way, it doesn't build on my machine either because of compile errors later on.)

Comment: What's the output of `C:\perl\bin\perl -MDBI -MDBI::DBD -e"print DBI::DBD->dbd_postamble"`? I think that's failing, the error is ignored, and the error message is suppressed.

Comment: >C:\perl\bin\perl -MDBI -MDBI::DBD -e"print DBI::DBD->dbd_postamble"
*** You're using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler or similar but
    the LIB and INCLUDE environment variables are not both set.

    You need to run the VCVARS32.BAT batch file that was supplied
    with the compiler before you can use it.

    A copy of vcvars32.bat can typically be found in the following
    directories under your Visual Studio install directory:
        Visual C++ 6.0:     vc98\bin
        Visual Studio .NET: vc7\bin

    Find it, run it, then retry this.

Comment: if I run vcvars32.bat nothing happens

Comment: I was able to install it on centOS  7 machine without problems

Comment: It should launch a new shell with certain env vars setup. Or do you mean you still get the same error from the command being run within that shell?

Comment: after I ran vcvars32.bat, then run the command C:\perl\bin\perl -MDBI -MDBI::DBD -e"print DBI::DBD->dbd_postamble", now I get the below message:

Comment: Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: C:/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/ C:/perl/lib/auto/DBI/ at -e line 1.
Using DBI 1.631 (for perl 5.016003 on MSWin32-x64-multi-thread) installed in C:/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/

# --- This section was generated by DBI::DBD::dbd_postamble()
DBI_INSTARCH_DIR=C:\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI
DBI_DRIVER_XST=C:\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI\Driver.xst

# The main dependency (technically correct but probably not used)
$(BASEEXT).c: $(BASEEXT).xsi

# This dependency is needed since MakeMaker uses the .xs.o rule
$(BASEEXT)$(OBJ_EXT): $(BASEEXT).xsi

Comment: $(BASEEXT).xsi: $(DBI_DRIVER_XST) C:\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI\Driver_xst.h
        $(PERL) -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/$(BASEEXT)/g" $(DBI_DRIVER_XST) > $(BASEEXT).xsi

# ---

Comment: That looks right. Now run `cpan DBD::SQLcipher` from within that shell

Comment: sqlite3.c(16507): warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(205): note: see declaration of 'fopen'
sqlite3.c(16824): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/rand.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'

Comment: Sounds like it needs the openssl library --including header files-- to be available.

Comment: I installed openssl under C:\OpenSSL-Win64\ and set that path and restarted windows still same error  Cannot open include file: 'openssl/rand.h. how to tell where it is located, I see it in C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl

Comment: I copied the include/openssl folder to VC/include folder now new error:
sqlite3.c(16941): error C2079: 'hctx' uses undefined struct 'hmac_ctx_st'
....
sqlite3.c(16958): error C2079: 'ectx' uses undefined struct 'evp_cipher_ctx_st'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'

Comment: I have "SQLite Browser" windows program installed. It has sqlcipher.dll, can I use these.

Comment: Re "*how to tell where it is located*", Via the `INCLUDE` and `LIB` env vars, I think.

Comment: Re "*`'ectx' uses undefined struct 'evp_cipher_ctx_st'`*", I think that's the same error I was getting in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Rules that should be added to the makefile aren't being added because of an exception which is being ignored. You can verify this by running

```
perl -MDBI -MDBI::DBD -e"print DBI::DBD->dbd_postamble"
```

There error is probably the following:

```
*** You're using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler or similar but
    the LIB and INCLUDE environment variables are not both set.

    You need to run the VCVARS32.BAT batch file that was supplied
    with the compiler before you can use it.

    A copy of vcvars32.bat can typically be found in the following
    directories under your Visual Studio install directory:
        Visual C++ 6.0:     vc98\bin
        Visual Studio .NET: vc7\bin

    Find it, run it, then retry this.

    If you think this error is not correct then just set the LIB and
    INCLUDE environment variables to some value to disable the check.
```

If so, it's reminding you that you need to run `cpan DBD::SQLcipher` within the shell created by `vcvars32` as it will have environment variables needed by your compiler properly set.

Comment: Are you able to build it on windows? I followed your steps, now I am getting these errors: sqlite3.c(16941): error C2079: 'hctx' uses undefined struct 'hmac_ctx_st', sqlite3.c(16958): error C2079: 'ectx' uses undefined struct 'evp_cipher_ctx_st', sqlite3.c(16944): warning C4133: 'function': incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'HMAC_CTX *'

Comment: Didn't try on Windows. This is a question-answer site. You c asked a question, and this answered it. If you have more questions, post new Questions.

Comment: I know this is a question answer site and based on your answer I asked another question, you changed your comment to answer so I supposed you tried it and success, thanks.

Comment: You're missing the point. The comments are not the place for new questions. // I changed my comment into an answer because you confirmed that it answered your question

Comment: no problem, just posted it as a new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743756/perl-compile-sqlcipher-on-windows-error-c2079-hctx-uses-undefined-struct-hmac-ct